# mysql - how to retrieve two distincts time intervals from two different providers?

Tags: mysql, sql

heres my problem: I have a table that insert some timestamps where my store get the daily deliverers, but i have two different providers "Provider_1" and "Provider_2" which is a routine, so they must meet the deadline. but the problen is provider_1 routine is different from provider_2, and i'm trying to bring it on a single query that shows, whether or not they are on schedule. and so far thats what i managed to do by myself:

```
CREATE TABLE deliveries (
    provider_Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    provider_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    deliver_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    finished_delivered DATETIME NOT NULL,
    started_new_deliver DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(provider_Id)
)
;

-- data
INSERT INTO deliveries
    (provider_name, deliver_time, finished_delivered, started_new_deliver)
VALUES
    ('Provider_1', '2020-05-16 4:59:59','2020-02-16 8:59:00' ,'2020-02-16 11:32:00' 
    ('Provider_2','2020-05-16 8:31:59', '2020-02-16 11:50:59', '2020-02-16 12:35:00'),
    ('Provider_1', '2020-02-17 4:54:59', '2020-02-17 7:45:09','2020-02-17 11:03:09'),
    ('Provider_2','2020-02-17 10:00:59', '2020-02-17 12:40:59','2020-02-17 14:06:39'),
    ('Provider_1','2020-02-18 7:00:59', '2020-02-18 10:28:59', '2020-02-18 14:36:39')
```

and thats my select for Provider_1:

```
SELECT
IF(deliveries.deliver_time IS NULL,NULL,IF(TIME(deliveries.deliver_time) BETWEEN '3:59:59' AND '5:59:59','1','0')) as delivered, 
 IF(deliveries.finished_delivered IS NULL,NULL,IF(TIME(deliveries.finished_delivered) BETWEEN '4:59:59' AND '6:59:59' ,'1','0')) as finished_delivered, 
IF(deliveries.started_new_deliver IS NULL,NULL,IF(TIME(deliveries.started_new_deliver) BETWEEN '7:29:59' AND '9:29:59','1','0')) as started_new_deliver
 FROM  deliveries      
 WHERE  deliveries.provider_name LIKE "Provider_1" 
 ORDER BY       deliveries.provider_Id DESC
```

i must do about the same thing for Provider_2, but i need to have different time intervals and the Query for both gotta be a single one, not two. Heres a table with the Provider_2 intervals:

```
+-----------------+--------------------+---------------------+
| deliver_time    | finished_delivered | started_new_deliver |
+-----------------+--------------------+---------------------+
| 7:59:59-9:59:59 | 9:59:59-11:59:59   | 11:59:59-13:59:59   |
+-----------------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Please explain the *logic* you want to implement.  It is clear what you are trying to accomplish.  Wouldn't just leaving out the `where` clause do what you want?

Comment: i trying to return a simple true or false for my Providers accordingly to the agreement time, if theyre accomplishing the routine or not, but i need that on a single query. the where clause may not solve my problem, because the timestamps of the agreement for the provider_1(showed on the query)  and for provider_2(showed on the table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a derived table with the times that you want.  You can then join this in:

```
SELECT (TIME(d.deliver_time) BETWEEN p.t1 AND p.t2) as delivered, 
       (TIME(d.finished_delivered) BETWEEN p.t3 AND p.t4) as finished_delivered, 
       (TIME(d.started_new_deliver) BETWEEN p.t5 AND p.t6),'1','0')) as started_new_deliver
FROM (SELECT 'Provider_1' as provider_name, '3:59:59' as t1, '5:59:59' as t2, '4:59:59' as t3, '6:59:59' as t4, '7:29:59' as t5, '9:29:59' as t6
     ) p JOIN
     deliveries d     
     ON d.provider_name = p.provider_name
ORDER BY d.provider_Id DESC
```

For the second provider, this would look like:

```
FROM (SELECT 'Provider_1' as provider_name, '3:59:59' as t1, '5:59:59' as t2, '4:59:59' as t3, '6:59:59' as t4, '7:29:59' as t5, '9:29:59' as t6
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Provider_2' as provider_name, '3:59:59' as t1, '5:59:59' as t2, '4:59:59' as t3, '6:59:59' as t4, '7:29:59' as t5, '9:29:59' as t6          
     ) p JOIN
```

But you would adjust the times to be what you want.

Note that I simplified the logic for the flags.  This logic returns `0`/`1` as numbers or `NULL` if the column is `NULL`.

Comment: ur answer really helped me, not only by giving the answer but i always learning something new every time i ask a question around here! so thank you! =)